# Android, separate drawtext on canvas next to each other

Tags: java, android

Im struggling to find a solution this problem. 
Basically I have 3 separate strings that are drawn on the canvas in different colors. Ie:

```
Canvas.drawtext(text, x, y, mpaint1);
Canvas.drawtext(text2, x, y, mpaint2);
Canvas.drawtext(text3, x, y, mpaint3);
```

At the moment they are positioned next to each other using the x axis, using Px. This is a solution but doesn't work right in real world. 
Higher dpi will make the Px smaller.

I've tried, Html doesn't work, I've tried SpannableString but I can't seem to even get android studio to a acknowledged SpannableString. I also can't seem to import Java.awt.graphics?

Added note I'm extending canvaswatchfaveservice

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try this `canvas.drawText(text, (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, x, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()), y, mpaint1);`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I sort of understand, but do I need to call or import typedvalue? As it just shows red atm. Doesn't recognise it.

Comment: Yes you have to import it.Place cursor on TypedValue and  `Lalt + Enter` will give you the option to import .

Comment: It actually doesn't give me the option to import everything but.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have different solution to your problem.

you should take one `LinerarLayout` with vertical orientation having 3 `TextView` and then you set your text into TextView and then you will get Bitmap form `LinerarLayout` and draw that Bitmap on canvas.

Also in this way you have liberty to set Background color , text color , font style  and all other properties of `TextView`.

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.layout(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean? But Im not linking to any xml. Everything is drawn to canvas?